# disabling require_secure_transport mysql

Tags: mysql, environment-variables, ssl

How do i disable the mysql variable require_secure_transport permanently? I have to access mysql with node.js, and it is giving me the following error:

```
  code: 'ER_SECURE_TRANSPORT_REQUIRED',
  errno: 3159,
  sqlMessage: 'Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.',
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  fatal: true }
```

For reference, this is the one I am talking about https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_require_secure_transport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up deleting the following line: `require_secure_transport = ON` from the file `etc/mysql/conf.d`